# Stress/impact simulation of a solidworks design

Tags: mechanical-engineering, solidworks, cad, simulation

I am creating a waterproof box that will be submerged under a few feet of soil and also must be able to withstand the impact if dropped from a height.

I am wondering if it is possible on solidworks, to simulate the box under a load (weight of the soil) to see if the box can withstand the weight. Or will i require a different software?

Also how may i simulate the impacts encountered during a fall?

thank you very much

Comment: Your description of the questions does make sense. I read as, the box will drop a few feet to the ground, then be buried under the soil, can Solidworks simulate it and check whether the box can endure the impact and soil loads or not? Please review and edit/update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Both simulations can be performed in Solidworks.

the first one I'd model it as a uniform pressure outside of the box (in the appropriate surfaces). Any decent

The second one (drop test), solidworks has drop testing workflow. You can see an example [at this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dn9kIDAaP2g)